# Rearranging the structure of many txt files and then merging them in one data frame

Tags: regex, r, merge, dataframe, text-files

I would appreciate your help with this a lot!

I have ~4.5k txt files which look like this:

```
Simple statistics using MSPA parameters: 8_3_1_1 on input file: 20130815 104359  875  000000 0528 0548_result.tif

 MSPA-class [color]:  Foreground/data pixels [%]  Frequency
============================================================
    CORE(s) [green]:               --                   0
    CORE(m) [green]:      48.43/13.45                   1
    CORE(l) [green]:               --                   0
      ISLET [brown]:       3.70/ 1.03                  20
 PERFORATION [blue]:       0.00/ 0.00                   0
       EDGE [black]:      30.93/ 8.59                  11
      LOOP [yellow]:       9.66/ 2.68                   6
       BRIDGE [red]:       0.00/ 0.00                   0
    BRANCH [orange]:       7.28/ 2.02                  40
  Background [grey]:       --- /72.22                  11
    Missing [white]:            0.00                    0
```

I want to read all txt files from a directory into R and then perform a rearranging task on them before merging them together.

The values in the txt files can change, so in places where there is a 0.00 now, could be a relevant number in some files (so we need those). For the fields where there are -- now, it would be good if the script could test if there are -- , or a number. If there are the --, then it should turn them into NAs. On the other hand, real 0.00 values are of value and I need them. There is only one value for the Missing white column (or row here), that value should then be copied into both columns, foreground% and data pixels%.

The general rearranging which I need is to make all the data available as columns with only 1 row per txt file. For every row of data in the txt file here, there should be 3 columns in the output file (foreground%, data pixel% and frequency for every color). The name of the row should be the image name which is mentioned in the beginning of the file, here: 20130815 104359  875  000000 0528 0548

The rest can be omitted.

The output should look something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxCGG.png]

I am working on this simultaneously but am not sure which direction to take. So any help is more than welcome!

Best,
Moritz

Comment: I don't see how the sample data can match up with the image you posted

Comment: Well, all the data in the file is for an certain case, see the string at the beginning of the txt file. So, instead of having column foreground% and row core(m) for example we make a column called foreground_core_m and the row 20130815 104359 875 000000 0528 0548. The value is then 48.43. Same for datapixels_core_m which would then use the same row and the value would be 13.45. Is that more understandable? I am not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This puts it in the format you want, I think, but the example doesn't match your image so I can't be sure:

```
(lf <- list.files('~/desktop', pattern = '^image\\d+.txt', full.names = TRUE))
# [1] "/Users/rawr/desktop/image001.txt" "/Users/rawr/desktop/image002.txt"
# [3] "/Users/rawr/desktop/image003.txt"

lapply(lf, function(xx) {
  rl <- readLines(con <- file(xx), warn = FALSE)
  close(con)
  ## assuming the file name is after "file: " until the end of the string
  ## and ends in .tif
  img_name <- gsub('.*file:\\s+(.*).tif', '\\1', rl[1])
  ## removes each string up to and including the ===== string
  rl <- rl[-(1:grep('==', rl))]
  ## remove leading whitespace
  rl <- gsub('^\\s+', '', rl)

  ## split the remaining lines by larger chunks of whitespace
  mat <- do.call('rbind', strsplit(rl, '\\s{2, }'))
  ## more cleaning, setting attributes, etc
  mat[mat == '--'] <- NA
  mat <- cbind(image_name = img_name, `colnames<-`(t(mat[, 2]), mat[, 1]))
  as.data.frame(mat)
})
```

I created three files using your example and made each one slightly different to show how this would work on a directory with several files:

```
# [[1]]
#                                        image_name CORE(s) [green]: CORE(m) [green]: CORE(l) [green]: ISLET [brown]:   PERFORATION [blue]: EDGE [black]: LOOP [yellow]: BRIDGE [red]: BRANCH [orange]: Background [grey]: Missing [white]:
#   1 20130815 104359  875  000000 0528 0548_result             <NA>      48.43/13.45             <NA>     3.70/ 1.03          0.00/ 0.00     30.93/ 8.59     9.66/ 2.68    0.00/ 0.00       7.28/ 2.02         --- /72.22             0.00
# 
# [[2]]
#                                        image_name CORE(s) [green]: CORE(m) [green]: CORE(l) [green]: ISLET [brown]:   PERFORATION [blue]: EDGE [black]: LOOP [yellow]: BRIDGE [red]: BRANCH [orange]: Background [grey]: Missing [white]:
#   1 20139341 104359  875  000000 0528 0548_result               23      48.43/13.45               23           <NA>          0.00/ 0.00     30.93/ 8.59     9.66/ 2.68    0.00/ 0.00       7.28/ 2.02         --- /72.22             0.00
# 
# [[3]]
#                                        image_name CORE(s) [green]: CORE(m) [green]: CORE(l) [green]: ISLET [brown]: PERFORATION [blue]:  EDGE [black]: LOOP [yellow]: BRIDGE [red]: BRANCH [orange]: Background [grey]: Missing [white]:
#   1 20132343 104359  875  000000 0528 0548_result             <NA>             <NA>             <NA>           <NA>                <NA>    30.93/ 8.59     9.66/ 2.68    0.00/ 0.00       7.28/ 2.02               <NA>             0.00
```

EDIT

made a few changes to extract all the info:

```
(lf <- list.files('~/desktop', pattern = '^image\\d+.txt', full.names = TRUE))
# [1] "/Users/rawr/desktop/image001.txt" "/Users/rawr/desktop/image002.txt"
# [3] "/Users/rawr/desktop/image003.txt"

res <- lapply(lf, function(xx) {
  rl <- readLines(con <- file(xx), warn = FALSE)
  close(con)
  img_name <- gsub('.*file:\\s+(.*).tif', '\\1', rl[1])
  rl <- rl[-(1:grep('==', rl))]
  rl <- gsub('^\\s+', '', rl)
  mat <- do.call('rbind', strsplit(rl, '\\s{2, }'))
  dat <- as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  tmp <- `colnames<-`(do.call('rbind', strsplit(dat$V2, '[-\\/\\s]+', perl = TRUE)),
                      c('Foreground','Data pixels'))
  dat <- cbind(dat[, -2], tmp, image_name = img_name)
  dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.character)
  dat[dat == ''] <- NA
  names(dat)[1:2] <- c('MSPA-class','Frequency')

  zzz <- reshape(dat, direction = 'wide', idvar = 'image_name', timevar = 'MSPA-class')
  names(zzz)[-1] <- gsub('(.*)\\.(.*) (?:.*)', '\\2_\\1', names(zzz)[-1], perl = TRUE)
  zzz
})
```

here is the result (I just transformed into a long matrix so it would be easier to read. the real results are in a very wide data frame, one for each file):

```
`rownames<-`(matrix(res[[1]]), names(res[[1]]))
# [,1]                                           
# image_name              "20130815 104359  875  000000 0528 0548_result"
# CORE(s)_Frequency       "0"                                            
# CORE(s)_Foreground      "NA"                                           
# CORE(s)_Data pixels     "NA"                                           
# CORE(m)_Frequency       "1"                                            
# CORE(m)_Foreground      "48.43"                                        
# CORE(m)_Data pixels     "13.45"                                        
# CORE(l)_Frequency       "0"                                            
# CORE(l)_Foreground      "NA"                                           
# CORE(l)_Data pixels     "NA"                                           
# ISLET_Frequency         "20"                                           
# ISLET_Foreground        "3.70"                                         
# ISLET_Data pixels       "1.03"                                         
# PERFORATION_Frequency   "0"                                            
# PERFORATION_Foreground  "0.00"                                         
# PERFORATION_Data pixels "0.00"                                         
# EDGE_Frequency          "11"                                           
# EDGE_Foreground         "30.93"                                        
# EDGE_Data pixels        "8.59"                                         
# LOOP_Frequency          "6"                                            
# LOOP_Foreground         "9.66"                                         
# LOOP_Data pixels        "2.68"                                         
# BRIDGE_Frequency        "0"                                            
# BRIDGE_Foreground       "0.00"                                         
# BRIDGE_Data pixels      "0.00"                                         
# BRANCH_Frequency        "40"                                           
# BRANCH_Foreground       "7.28"                                         
# BRANCH_Data pixels      "2.02"                                         
# Background_Frequency    "11"                                           
# Background_Foreground   "NA"                                           
# Background_Data pixels  "72.22"                                        
# Missing_Frequency       "0"                                            
# Missing_Foreground      "0.00"                                         
# Missing_Data pixels     "0.00"
```

with your sample data:

```
lf <- list.files('~/desktop/data', pattern = '.txt', full.names = TRUE)

`rownames<-`(matrix(res[[1]]), names(res[[1]]))

#                         [,1]                                    
# image_name              "20130815 103704  780  000000 0372 0616"
# CORE(s)_Frequency       "0"                                     
# CORE(s)_Foreground      "NA"                                    
# CORE(s)_Data pixels     "NA"                                    
# CORE(m)_Frequency       "1"                                     
# CORE(m)_Foreground      "54.18"                                 
# CORE(m)_Data pixels     "15.16"                                 
# CORE(l)_Frequency       "0"                                     
# CORE(l)_Foreground      "NA"                                    
# CORE(l)_Data pixels     "NA"                                    
# ISLET_Frequency         "11"                                    
# ISLET_Foreground        "3.14"                                  
# ISLET_Data pixels       "0.88"                                  
# PERFORATION_Frequency   "0"                                     
# PERFORATION_Foreground  "0.00"                                  
# PERFORATION_Data pixels "0.00"                                  
# EDGE_Frequency          "1"                                     
# EDGE_Foreground         "34.82"                                 
# EDGE_Data pixels        "9.75"                                  
# LOOP_Frequency          "1"                                     
# LOOP_Foreground         "4.96"                                  
# LOOP_Data pixels        "1.39"                                  
# BRIDGE_Frequency        "0"                                     
# BRIDGE_Foreground       "0.00"                                  
# BRIDGE_Data pixels      "0.00"                                  
# BRANCH_Frequency        "20"                                    
# BRANCH_Foreground       "2.89"                                  
# BRANCH_Data pixels      "0.81"                                  
# Background_Frequency    "1"                                     
# Background_Foreground   "NA"                                    
# Background_Data pixels  "72.01"                                 
# Missing_Frequency       "0"                                     
# Missing_Foreground      "0.00"                                  
# Missing_Data pixels     "0.00"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check it. In the meantime I provided a comment on how I think one can get the data in the format I need (where you made the comment in the original question)

Comment: Hm, unfortunately not. I get this:  Error in strsplit(dat$V2, "[-\\/\\s]+", perl = TRUE) : non-character argument. Got a link to some data files for you here, probably easiest to fix the problem. Thanks! https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f7trh2148otwnrq/AACMt46DSQkIkJ1RTVU6zG8ja?dl=0

Comment: fixed the last lines so that the names are more in line with what youre looking for. maybe `dat` as factors? check `str(dat)` thats what the `dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.character)` line was for

Comment: code seems to be working for me. I used `lf <- list.files('~/desktop/data', pattern = '.txt', full.names = TRUE)` to get the paths to the files and ran the new `lapply` function

Comment: @MoritzSchmid see edits, just ran it on your data files

Comment: Thanks man. Still getting: Error in strsplit(dat$V2, "[-\\/\\s]+", perl = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument, but working on it. Are you loading any packages?

Comment: nope. just restarted r and still works. I can reproduce your error if I do `strsplit(NULL, 'anything')` or `strsplit(NA, 'anything')`, so make sure that `V2` is a variable in `dat`

Comment: I updated R and R studio, now it works. Had the last versions of both. So, advice, always update -.- Thanks a lot!

Comment: Rawr, I almost feel bad, but could you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423270/recursively-extracting-values-from-within-a-text-file-and-looping-over-more-of-t?

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your data on a text file and adjusted the space in order to have consistency between them. You might want to do it or if you can attach a text file, it would be easy to work with. You may use pastebin - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin

First set your working directory as follows:

```
setwd("path of your file")
```

#EDIT: Create a single data frame of all files

```
split.row.data <- function(x){

  a1 = sub("( )+(.*)", '\\2', x)

  b1 = unlist(strsplit(sub("( )+(.*)", '\\2', (strsplit(a1, ":"))[[1]][2]), "  "))

  c1 = unlist(strsplit(b1[1], "/"))

  if(length(c1) == 1){
    if(which(b1[1:2] %in% "") == 1){
      c1 = c(NA, c1)
    }else if(which(b1[1:2] %in% "") == 2){
      c1 = c(c1, NA)
    }
  }

  c1[which(c1 %in% c("--", "--- "))] <- NA

  return(c(unlist(strsplit(strsplit(a1, ":")[[1]][1], " ")), 
           c1,
           b1[length(b1)]))
}

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = 6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

file_list = list.files('~/desktop', pattern = '^image\\d+.txt', full.names = TRUE)

for (infile in file_list){

  file_data <- readLines(con <- file(infile))

  close(con)

  filename = sub("(.*)(input file:)(.*)(.tif)", "\\3", file_data[3])

  a2 <- file_data[7:length(file_data)]

  d1 = lapply(a2, function(x) split.row.data(x))

  df1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow= length(d1), ncol = 5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  for(i in 1:length(d1)){df1[i, ] <- d1[[i]]}

  df1 <- cbind(data.frame(rep(filename, nrow(df1)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
               df1)

  colnames(df1) <- colnames(df2)

  df2 <- rbind(df2, df1)

}

df2 <- df2[2:nrow(df2), ]

df2[,4] <- as.numeric(df2[,4])

df2[,5] <- as.numeric(df2[,5])

df2[,6] <- as.numeric(df2[,6])

e1 = unlist(lapply(df2[,3], function(x) gsub(']', '', x)))

df2[,3] = unlist(lapply(e1, function(x) gsub("[[]", '', x)))

header_names <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(file_data[5], "/"), function(x) strsplit(x, "  ")))

colnames(df2) <- c("filename",  
                   strsplit(header_names[1], " ")[[1]][2],
                   "color", 
                   header_names[2:length(header_names)])

row.names(df2) <- 1:nrow(df2)
```

output:

```
print(head(df2))

    filename                               MSPA-class  color  Foreground  data pixels [%] Frequency
 1  20130815 103739  599  000000 0944 0788     CORE(s) green         NA         NA         0
 2  20130815 103739  599  000000 0944 0788     CORE(m) green      63.46         17.41      1
 3  20130815 103739  599  000000 0944 0788     CORE(l) green         NA         NA         0
 4  20130815 103739  599  000000 0944 0788       ISLET brown       0.00         0.00       0
 5  20130815 103739  599  000000 0944 0788 PERFORATION  blue       0.00         0.00       0
 6  20130815 103739  599  000000 0944 0788        EDGE black      35.00         9.60       1
```

#get data for only "background" from "MSPA-class" column

```
df2_background  <- df2[which(df2[, "MSPA-class"] %in% "Background"), ]

print(df2_background)

    filename                               MSPA-class  color  Foreground  data pixels [%] Frequency
11  20130815 103739  599  000000 0944 0788 Background  grey         NA    72.57           1
22  20130815 143233  712  000000 1048 0520 Background  grey         NA    77.51           1
33  20130902 163929  019  000000 0394 0290 Background  grey         NA    54.55           6
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. I was able to reproduce it nicely here. I am working now on splitting the data on foreground and data pixel columns as described above, and we can in fact drop the color column. Any idea how I can get the data frame in a format where I only have 1 row that has as value the name of the image (currently that information is lost in your code ) and the rows we have right now also go as columns?

Comment: And, in fact the part where you define the structure makes this only applicable to this one file. Can you help to change it so that that part works in the for loop and for many files? Here 3 example files in pastebin! http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=5gg9WNaN

Comment: you could use `na.strings = '--'` in read.table and skip that step