# Recursively extracting values from within a text file and looping over more of them plus rearranging rows and columns

Tags: regex, r, function, dataframe, lapply

I want to extract values from several hundred txt files based on a regex pattern, rearrange them and write them into a data frame.

The beginning of the file starts like this: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=vdbXfDhC

and ends like this: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=hse7SDJd

I had a similar question earlier ([Rearranging the structure of many txt files and then merging them in one data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399820/rearranging-the-structure-of-many-txt-files-and-then-merging-them-in-one-data-fr))
where rawr provided me with this code:

```
(lf <- list.files('~/desktop', pattern = '^image\\d+.txt', full.names = TRUE))
# [1] "/Users/rawr/desktop/image001.txt" "/Users/rawr/desktop/image002.txt"
# [3] "/Users/rawr/desktop/image003.txt"

res <- lapply(lf, function(xx) {
  rl <- readLines(con <- file(xx), warn = FALSE)
  close(con)
  img_name <- gsub('.*file:\\s+(.*).tif', '\\1', rl[1])
  rl <- rl[-(1:grep('==', rl))]
  rl <- gsub('^\\s+', '', rl)
  mat <- do.call('rbind', strsplit(rl, '\\s{2, }'))
  dat <- as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  tmp <- `colnames<-`(do.call('rbind', strsplit(dat$V2, '[-\\/\\s]+', perl = TRUE)),
                      c('Foreground','Data pixels'))
  dat <- cbind(dat[, -2], tmp, image_name = img_name)
  dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.character)
  dat[dat == ''] <- NA
  names(dat)[1:2] <- c('MSPA-class','Frequency')

  zzz <- reshape(dat, direction = 'wide', idvar = 'image_name', timevar = 'MSPA-class')
  names(zzz)[-1] <- gsub('(.*)\\.(.*) (?:.*)', '\\2_\\1', names(zzz)[-1], perl = TRUE)
  zzz
})
```

However, this code was using txt files where there was only one analysis step per file, now I have many analyses in one .log file as shown in the pastebin example (1/745 ... etc.) so I can't use the same loop.

Can somebody help me adapt the code posted above to extract

1) MeshSize: XXX [ha]
2) rel. fragmentation: XXX
3) MeshSize comp.time [sec]: XXX

for every image (e.g., ==============   703/745   ============== denotes the new image with the image name coming in the path)

Similar as in my other question I need the data rearranged so that the image name (the string in the path ending with .tif: 20130815 225017  957  000000 0892 0464) is the row name (I don't need the .tif ending) and 1) MeshSize[ha], 2) rel. fragmentation 3) MeshSize comp.time [sec] are columns.

```
image name    1) mesh size 2).....  3)......
   row1              xx        xx      xx
   row2
```

**Edit to rawr's great solution**

If you want the whole thing in a loop and saved as CSV, you can do it like this:

```
lf =  list.files(path="xx", pattern = '^batch_mesh8\\d.log', full.names = TRUE)

mesh2<-NULL

for (i in lf)
{

#rawr's code here:

#final lines of code:
mesh1<-cbind(data.frame('image_name' = img_names), mat)
mesh2 <- rbind(mesh2, mesh1)
}
write.csv(mesh2, file = "all_mesh_th8.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one is more straight-forward. (or maybe I made the other question harder than it was)

```
path <- '~/desktop/log.log'
x <- readLines(con <- file(path))
close(con)

# m <- gregexpr('(\\d+/\\d+)', x, perl = TRUE)
# img_names <- head(unlist(regmatches(x, m)), -1)
# completed <- tail(img_names, 1)

y <- x[grepl('File', x)]
img_names <- basename(gsub('File: ', '', gsub('\\\\+','/', y), perl = TRUE))
img_names <- gsub('\\.([[:alnum:]]+)$','', img_names)

(x <- x[grepl('\\d+\\.\\d+', x)])

# [1] "MeshSize: 0.30289606 [ha]; rel. fragmentation: 83.1300" 
# [2] "MeshSize comp.time [sec]:    0.00099992752"             
# [3] "MeshSize: 0.39157622 [ha]; rel. fragmentation: 81.4600" 
# [4] "MeshSize comp.time [sec]:    0.00099992752"             
# [5] "MeshSize: 0.45971902 [ha]; rel. fragmentation: 76.8700" 
# [6] "MeshSize comp.time [sec]:       0.00000000"             
# [7] "MeshSize: 0.032965344 [ha]; rel. fragmentation: 94.5500"
# [8] "MeshSize comp.time [sec]:       0.00000000"             
# [9] "MeshSize: 0.034653125 [ha]; rel. fragmentation: 93.6300"
# [10] "MeshSize comp.time [sec]:       0.00000000"             
# [11] "MeshSize: 0.74313322 [ha]; rel. fragmentation: 90.2700" 
# [12] "MeshSize comp.time [sec]:    0.00099992752"             
# [13] "MeshSize: 0.48677515 [ha]; rel. fragmentation: 85.5700" 
# [14] "MeshSize comp.time [sec]:    0.00099992752" 

nums <- unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\d+\\.\\d+', x, perl = TRUE)))
mat <- matrix(nums, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, 
              dimnames = list(NULL, c('Mesh size','rel frag','comp time')))
cbind(data.frame('image_name' = img_names), mat)

#                               image_name   Mesh size rel frag     comp time
# 1 20130815 143656  507  000000 0952 0536  0.30289606  83.1300 0.00099992752
# 2 20130815 143657  673  000002 0244 0284  0.39157622  81.4600 0.00099992752
# 3 20130815 143657  706  000000 0764 0304  0.45971902  76.8700    0.00000000
# 4 20130815 143658  806  000000 0776 0672 0.032965344  94.5500    0.00000000
# 5 20130815 143700  005  000000 0232 0116 0.034653125  93.6300    0.00000000
# 6 20130815 225020  589  000000 0188 0564  0.74313322  90.2700 0.00099992752
# 7 20130815 225033  917  000000 0288 0804  0.48677515  85.5700 0.00099992752
```

Comment: Great, almost there. Just the names of the images should not be 1/745 etc. but the last part of the path string (e.b., 20130815 143657  673  000002 0244 0284). I guess after that I can easily pack it into a loop to take several log files and rbind them! Thanks a million!

Comment: ah, I don't read questions very well, and i forgot about the loop. that is probably easier than what I did. if you have a file path, `?basename` extracts the file name (with extension); then you can sub out the extension if you want (see edits)